# Centos web server, 123-reg domaina nd DynDNS standard - cannot access site from domain, only IP

Tags: centos, web-server, ip, dyndns

How to configure a 123-reg domain with DynDNS and a linux server?
Hi,

I've just set up a CentOS web server running lamp, purchased a domain from 123-reg and have signed up for DynDNS standard.

I'm really confused how I get the domain to link in with Dyn.

The client updater is working fine and I can access the website from the public IP, but whenever I go to the domain it just tells me it's a 123-reg domain.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Btw, I'm running a dynamic IP

Comment: Dynamic IP? Are you hosting this from home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transfer the domain to DynDNS. Right now, it is probably pointing to 123-reg's NS servers.

DynDNS' Support Site will have all the information you need: http://dyn.com/support/how-do-i-transfer-my-domain/

If you are setting up a business from home, you might want to contact your ISP regarding a static public IP